# mysql - Count Number of Rows returns 1 if there is no value

Tags: mysql, sql

May I know how to count the number of staff using the count? From the code that I made, I am able to get the result but it will still count as 1 if there is no staff on that location.

```
    $sql = "SELECT mlk.lokasi, staff.staff_id, count(*) as staff_number 
    FROM staff RIGHT JOIN mlk on mlk.l_id=staff.l_id
    GROUP BY mlk.lokasi 
    ORDER BY mlk.lokasi";
```

1. mlk - List of Locations.
2. staff - Staff details

Comment: add sample data for these tables with expected output

Comment: what do you want to count exactly ?

Comment: I want to count the number of staff. I am able to get the result but let say if that particular location has no staff available, the result will count as 1 not 0.

Comment: @Mr.Bhosale, eg that I want is, `Kuala Lumpur | 5, Johor | 3, Petaling Jaya | 0`

Comment: @Amran try the answer I posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"SELECT mlk.lokasi, count(staff.staff_id) as staff_number FROM staff RIGHT JOIN mlk on mlk.l_id=staff.l_id GROUP BY mlk.lokasi ORDER BY mlk.lokasi";
```

try this rather then using *

Comment: Thank you for the help but I get this error, `Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given`

Comment: @Amran are you using php ??

Comment: yap, I got it! my updated sql `SELECT mlk.lokasi, count(staff.staff_id) as staff_number 
        FROM staff RIGHT JOIN mlk on mlk.l_id=staff.l_id
        GROUP BY mlk.lokasi 
        ORDER BY mlk.lokasi`

Comment: Thanks for the idea and help @BOSS

Comment: @Amran no  problem I am updating the answer :) accept the answer so that other know this issue has been resolved :)